# Error when attempting to execute SQL Update

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

[image: This shows an example of the row in the database that I am attempting to Update]I am trying to update a Sql DB from a Windows Forms Application in C# and I keep running into this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PKtblStepCAB0D0D86002590DC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblStepConfiguration_Cond'. The duplicate key value is (1, 5, 20, 3, 1).

I understand what it is trying to say, but the thing is I am not trying to insert anything. I am trying to update it using the following.

```
private void SqlUpdateCommand(String DataBase, String DB_ColumnName, TextBox tb_changed, String Cond_ID, String Cond_GroupID)
{
  int rows = 0;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb_ConfigID.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb_SequenceID.Text))
  {
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LAP_Configuration.Properties.Settings.LAPConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    Console.WriteLine("Connection String: {0}\n", constr);
    conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    try
    {
      conn.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + DataBase + " SET "+DB_ColumnName +" = @NewName" +
                                               " WHERE (SequenceID = @SequenceNumber AND MasterConfig = @MasterConfig AND StepNumber = @StepNumber AND Con_ID = @Con_ID AND Con_GroupID = @Cond_GroupID)", conn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SequenceNumber", SeqSelected);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterConfig", ConfigSelect);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewName", tb_changed.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StepNumber", StepID);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Con_ID", Cond_ID);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cond_GroupID", Cond_GroupID);
      rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    finally
    {
      if (conn != null)
      {
        conn.Close();
      }
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice to solve the issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrSzK.png)

Comment: Is there a trigger that inserts a record with your update statement? That could be what is causing the primary key violation.

Comment: are you trying to change column name of one of the tables ?

Comment: There are no triggers and no I am not changing the column names I am changing a value under a column name.

Comment: If I understand your question I think you are using the wrong query! if you want to change column name .use this command ALTER TABLE "table_name"
Change "column 1" "column 2" ["Data Type"];

Comment: I am trying to Update a value in the table not the column name

Comment: Can you add one output sql (populated with real values) ? Just output before Exec.

Comment: Do you mean from my C#?

Comment: Yes from C#, sql string used (as it comes out) .

Comment: But are you sure that `DB_ColumnName` is not set to the name of the PrimaryKey, and you are changing it another PrimeryKey - which ends with "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint "?

Comment: Means the sql_text used on `cmd.Exe`. Eg: `sqlTxt=update mytable set mycol = ...`

Comment: @FrankNielsen Think you right, it's trying to update a compound PK with an entry which already exists (so duplicate key error)

Comment: I found the error. I have an Overridden Method that wasn't cutting off the connection so it was trying to do something it wasn't supposed to do and simultaneously create to instances of an update

Comment: Learn that lesson well. ALWAYS suspect your code is doing something it shouldn't. Note also that you do NOT update "database" - you update a table. Do not make your code more difficult to understand by using names that are misleading or add confusion. That is why some comments suggest very different actions.